# How to Invoke autocomplete jquery function when textbox clicked in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In my form, i have few selection controls and textboxes. I want to show autocomplete options in textbox getting value from database. THere are more records in database so im filtering the records by getting value from dropdown list in the same form . Im using jquery autocomplete functionality. But it doesn't working. When i click that textbox nothing is happening.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="Cmb_PrdCat" runat="server" Height="38px" ToolTip= "Product category"   Width="320px" ForeColor="#666666" CssClass="RoundedBtn" TabIndex="4"  >
 </asp:DropDownList>  

<asp:DropDownList ID="Cmb_Domain" runat="server" Height="38px" Width="321px" ForeColor="#666666" CssClass="RoundedBtn" TabIndex="3" >
 </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="Cmb_Reg" runat="server" Height="38px" Width="321px" ForeColor="#666666" CssClass="RoundedBtn" TabIndex="3" >
</asp:DropDownList>      

 <asp:TextBox ID="EndClient_Txt" runat="server" Width="317px"
 Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="#666666" 
  Height="31px"  CssClass="RoundedBtn" TabIndex="8" onfocus="SearchText()"></asp:TextBox>
```

**JQuery function:**

```
<link href="jquery/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<script src="jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="jquery/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">  

    function SearchText() {  
        $("#EndClient_Txt").autocomplete({  
            source: function(request, response) {  
                $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                    url: "SalesOrderInput.aspx/GetClientName",                         
                    dataType: "json",  
                    success: function(data) {  
                        response(data.d);  
                    },  
                    error: function(result) {  
                        alert("No Match");  
                    }  
                });  
            }  
        });  
    }  
</script>
```

In my aspx.vb page i coded like:

```
Public Function GetClientName() As List(Of String)

        Dim empResult As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

        Sql = "SELECT * FROM opportunities where PCategory ='" & Cmb_PrdCat.SelectedItem.Text & "' and Domain ='" & Cmb_Domain.SelectedItem.Text & "' and Region='" & Cmb_Reg.SelectedItem.Text & "'"

        Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(Sql, conn1)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While (reader.Read())
            empResult.Add(reader("OppName").ToString())
        End While
        reader.Close()
        Return empResult       

    End Function
```

WHen i start type something in that text box, error alert message is coming.

Comment: Looks like Web-Forms controls, correct? If so, the ID you are setting to the textbox is the server side id, but not necessarily the client side id. You need the client side id to add the jQuery autocomplete to the textbox.

Comment: You mean to say, debugger/cursor does not  reach at "success" or "error" function inside the ajax?

Comment: I mean the selector `$('#EndClient_Txt')` does not find any control on the page (client side) because the client side control name will be different for web-forms controls.

Comment: Yes the controls are from System.Web.UI.Controls. The id i set in aspx page is EndClient_Txt.   When i click Textbox it doesnt show even 'error' alert. If i have alert message above " $("#EndClient_Txt").autocomplete({  ". when i clcik text box, this alert msg is continously occuring.

Comment: Try to add "data" as parameter in Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the [PageMethod] or [WebMethod]  Annotations above the

```
Public Function GetClientName() As List(Of String)

End Function
```

Comment: By adding  <Services.WebMethod()> _ above my function is working. Here i have another problem , i have to change function declaration to 'shared'. Then only it is fetching the record. But when i declare like this, the instance variable cannot be used. i have to look other option for that. Anyway atleat it is working. So,i accepted yours as answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$("#EndClient_Txt")`

Try  `$("#<%= EndClient_Txt.ClientID %>")`

The `ClientID` property will ensure that you will always get the client control Id when the page is rendered

Comment: Even before adding this ClientID, when i type something in textbox, the alert msg for error is coming.

Comment: @Anu - Can you share the error? Although I'm sure that you cannot call a page function from a URL. Try adding `[WebMethod]` above the function declaration.